# Difference between Network file path and Direct file path?

Tags: c#, windows, file-io, file-permissions, filepath

I am currently working on an application that involves copying user files to a centralized location, and I have come across a behavioral issue.

When I reference the folder the files are copied to directly (ie. C:\FOLDER_PATH...), the code has no issues accessing the folder and the code runs as intended. However, when I use a Network path (ie. \\COMPUTER_NAME\c-root\FOLDER_PATH) I run into the error:
{"Access to the path '\\COMP_NAME\c-root\PATH\FILE_NAME' is denied."}

My code uses: `sourceFileInfo.CopyTo(destinationPath);` to copy the file.

As far as Windows security is concerned, I was wondering what the difference is between these two paths? As far as I can tell, they both access the same file location. I would appreciate someone clarifying this for me, and if there is a way I could use the Network path correctly and safely, I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: Permissions are set not only on the folder and files but also on the share.

Comment: There are File System permissions. And share permissions. Both must alling for you to have access. I have been taught to set the share to just allow everything and work with the File System permissions - they are more detailed and have more options. But we do not know if your test setup follows that pattern.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for pointing that out. I had not realized an app running on the same computer would trip the sharing permissions like that. I had assumed those referred to external users exclusively. I edited the sharing permissions, and it appears to be running correctly now.